# Kept logging out after I log it or move pages between two monitors

Tags: mac, display, mojave, login

This is somewhat complicated but simple.

I have two BenQ monitors with Mac Pro 2010(RX570 8gb).

(1) Im using MacOS Mojave but I can not log in cause my computer log out after 3 sec.

(2) I pull the power cord out for resetting and it worked fine for 10~30 min  but suddenly log out by itself especially if I move anything between two monitors.

If I connect only one monitor, then it's not a problem and I don't see any issues like logging out by itself. But once I connect two monitors, then I have problems. I assumed that Palette Master Element cause software issue so I formatted my computer for once. And yet, I still have this problem after I got MacOS Mojave. I've been using dual monitors for 2~3 years!! I don't understand why is it happening. In guest account, it works fine with two monitors but not in admin account.

I contacted both BenQ and Apple for several times but I can resolve this issue.

The real question is why MacOS log my computer out by itself? Any idea why?